# Python: convert list to dict (API POST)

Tags: python

I have the following:

```
    ra_int_tuples = set((d['name'], d['ipv4addr']) for d in ra_int)
    print(ra_int_tuples)
    ra_ext_tuples = set((d['name'], d['ipv4addr']) for d in ra_ext)
    print(ra_ext_tuples)

    new_addresses = [t for t in ra_int_tuples if t not in ra_ext_tuples]

    print(new_addresses)
```

this returns:

> [('test-rz-01.test.de', '10.60.1.100'), ('test2.test.de',
>   '10.60.1.10')]

I need to convert this to json (so I can POST back to the API).
I understood it's best to use a dict, so I used:

```
d = dict([(k, v) for k, v in zip(new_addresses[::2], new_addresses[1::2])])
```

but this gives me:

> {('test-rz-01.test.de', '10.60.1.100'): ('test2.test.de',
>   '10.60.1.10')}

instead of:

> {('test-rz-01.test.de': '10.60.1.100'), ('test2.test.de':
>   '10.60.1.10')}

I'm sure I'm missing something obviously.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the comprehension. `dict` can handle a list of tuples:

```
d = dict([('test-rz-01.test.de', '10.60.1.100'), ('test2.test.de', '10.60.1.10')])
# {'test-rz-01.test.de': '10.60.1.100', 'test2.test.de': '10.60.1.10'}
```